# Glitch when parent border is equal to child background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've come across a strange bug and I can't find any solution or someone with the same issue I'm currently having. When I place a parent element with a border and a border radius and overflow is hidden, then get the child element to be the same color as the parent's border color I get something like 1px inner transparent border. I know it is a graphic glitch, but is there a way to bypass this?

```
  .outside
  +border-radius(50%)
  width: 500px
  height: 500px
  border: 5px solid #696969
  overflow: hidden
  .inside
    width: 600px
    height: 300px
    margin-top: 300px
    background: #696969

<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/ricnunes/pen/wBqvzJ

Edit: Changed the SASS to CSS, so it's easier to see

```
.outside {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid #696969;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;

.outside .inside {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  background: #696969;
}
```

Comment: That just the subpixel issue I suspect, I'm sure this has come up before on SO

Comment: I don't se what you mean. I made a fiddle and fixed your CSS to work there. Would be great if you pasted actual CSS and not like you have above though. Here is the fiddle with only the code above. But may be we need to look at your "fiddle" to see what you mean?http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/ebtzjbg9/

Comment: I see the "transparent border" now. Had to go very close to the screen to see it though.

Comment: @Preben You don't have a fiddle, but I left a codepen with the example. On your fiddle, you don't have border-radius (my bad for not saying it was in SASS and not in CSS). That's why it probably was hard to see it.